# How move branch in tree and update them

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tree structure. But I don't know how to use recursive methods.

I'm making a drag and drop tree, and I dont know how to update a branch when move a branch position to other position.

I would like to creat a recursive method that when move that branch update tree.

For example:

```
const data  = [{
    "id": 0,
    "parentId": null,
    "level": 0,
    "title": "New Branch 0",
    "children": [],
    "position": 0
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "parentId": null,
    "level": 0,
    "title": "New Branch 1",
    "children": [{
        "id": 8,
        "parentId": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "title": "New Branch 8",
        "children": [],
        "position": 0
    }],
    "position": 1
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "parentId": null,
    "level": 0,
    "title": "New Branch 2",
    "children": [{
        "id": 5,
        "parentId": 2,
        "level": 1,
        "title": "New Branch 5",
        "children": [],
        "position": 0
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "parentId": 2,
        "level": 1,
        "title": "New Branch 6",
        "children": [{
            "id": 9,
            "parentId": 6,
            "level": 2,
            "title": "New Branch 9",
            "children": [],
            "position": 0
        }],
        "position": 1
    }, {
        "id": 7,
        "parentId": 2,
        "level": 1,
        "title": "New Branch 7",
        "children": [],
        "position": 2
    }],
    "position": 2
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "parentId": null,
    "level": 0,
    "title": "New Branch 3",
    "children": [],
    "position": 3
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "parentId": null,
    "level": 0,
    "title": "New Branch 4",
    "children": [],
    "position": 4
}]
```

So, If I move item with id 9 between items with id 0 and 1... element with id 6 has no children and element with id 9 update with parentId null and position 1.

And update their positions.

Comment: your tree is messed up. Why you have ID 2 in root but it says that parentId is `1` (instead of `null`) ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know how to find items in the tree? To add items? To remove items? Moving a node is the equivalent of deleting from one node and adding to another. In terms of using recursion, that probably is just for the find, and would be used both for the add (find parent; make changes) and the remove (find parent, make changes).

Comment: Sorry, because I copied from Json.stringgify and parentId is undefined and I have to add manually